# Meaning of *provided power* for working fluid in a heat pump cycle

Tags: thermodynamics

This is from a homework question, which I have been trying to solve for quite some time now. I will not ask for the whole solution, but just the meanings of the words used in this question. The question goes like this:

> An ideal vapor-compression heat pump cycle with refrigerant R134a as the working fluid provides $15 kW$ to maintain a building at $20^oC$ when the outside temperature is $5^oC$. Saturated vapor at $2.4\ bar$ leaves the evaporator, and saturated liquid at $8\ bar$ leaves the condenser. Calculate the power input to the compressor in $kW$ as well as the coefficient of performance.

Once again, I am going to say that I am NOT asking for a solution, which in itself, is not encouraged on this site. All I want is to understand which numerical value corresponds to which variable.[image]

Now I can easily see that $P_1=2.4\ bar$ and $P_2=P_3=8\ bar$
However what is $15 kW$? Is it the heat supplied from $4$ to $1$ or the heat rejected from $2$ to $3$? Also what is the use of the values $20^0C$ and $5^oC$ in this problem?

Thanks for your attention and I do apologize if I sounded naive.

Comment: 15 kW is the heat rejected into the building from the condenser, which is the sum of heat absorbed by the working fluid from the environment and the work done by the compressor.  The temperatures give you enough information to determine the pressures that your working fluid must experience as it is going through its cycle, which allows a calculation of power requirements (PV work divided by time).

Answer (score 0):

Just for guidance;

1. 15 kW is desired rate of heat transfer, which for a heat pump is the rate of heat transferred to the building interior at 20 C.
2. 5 C is the outdoor temperature. For an ideal reversible cycle this would be the saturation temperature of the fluid in the evaporator. For a real cycle the saturation temperature at the evaporator is less for heat transfer from the outdoors to occur.
3. 20 C is the interior temperature of the building. For an ideal reversible cycle this would be the saturation temperature of the fluid in the condenser. For a real cycle the saturation temperature at the condenser is greater than the indoor temperature for heat transfer to the indoors.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand from your description that $T_1=T_4=5^oC$ and $T_3=20^oc$. Am I correct?

Comment: But from the R134a tables, we can see that the saturation temperature at $P_1=2.4\ bar$ is $-5.37^oC$ and that at $P_3=8\ bar$ is $31.33^oC$. I was confused in the first place due to this.

Comment: Sorry,  I thought they were giving the saturation temperatures. I didn’t bother looking them up. So you already had your answer. The saturation temperature at the fluid in the evaporator has to be less than the outdoor temperature and greater than the indoor temperature for heat transfers to occur. I will revise my answer

Comment: I also have to add I was thinking about an ideal reversible cycle where the saturation temperatures are the same as the temperatures of the environments. I have added that to my answer